# backbone backgrid: how to avoid double change event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

I have a backbone/backgrid editable grid, and everytime I edit a cell the "change" event is fired up twice and I end up making two separate PUT requests.

I know that this happens because the "change" event fires once when I edit it in the cell, and another when the data comes back from the server; and that the behaviour could be avoided by passing `{wait: true}` to the `save` method, but I don't know where I need to overload it.

My model declaration is like this:

```
var Redirects = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/global/redirects',
    initialize: function () {
        Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        this.on("change", function (model, options) {
            if (options && options.save === false) return;
            model.save({
                error: alertMe
            });
        });

        this.on('fetch request', function (e) {
            loadingOn(e);
        });

        this.on('sync error', function (e) {
            loadingOff(e);
        });

        this.on('error', function(e, resp){
            alertMe(e, resp);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't receive a 2nd change event when a Model is synced from the server, regardless of the `wait` option.

The problem in your `save` call is that you haven't specified the `attributes` hash, i.e. the first parameter. If you don't have any attributes to modify, which considering you are firing save for a change event, that's probably the case, you will need the following:

```
    this.on("change", function (model, options) {
        if (options && options.save === false) return;
        model.save(null, {error: alertMe});
    });
```

What was actually happening was that you were setting `error` as an attribute on the model, and that triggered the `change` event.